# How to stop the "searching for GPS" in android

Tags: android, gps

i am trying to stop the "searching for GPS" in my app.
when i am using this line of code:

```
this.locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
```

i can still see the icon of the GPS in the notification bar, and its not stopping at all.
what else can i do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing this you should pass the location Listener instance to removeUpdate method like this.

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(gpsLocationListener);
```

where

```
GPSLocationListener gpsLocationListener = new GPSLocationListener();

class GPSOnChangeLocationListener implements LocationListener {
           public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}
           public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}
           public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {}
           public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {}
}
```

Comment: i dont know who did it... i didnt ever try it yet.

Comment: i am kinda new... so im not sure how can i do it..
my app is in the class thats implementing LocatinListner...

Comment: its hard becouse there is a lot of code...  ill try to explain what i do.
the main activity is implementing LoactionListner.
`private void registerLocationUpdates() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(ParkOGuardActivity.class.getName()
    + ".LOCATION_READY");

  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
  // minimum every 30 minutes, 300 kilometers 
  this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(this.provider, 30000,
    300000, pendingIntent);
 }

 private void cancelLocationUpdates() {
  locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
 }`

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out.
thats what i did and it works:

```
private void registerLocationUpdates() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ParkOGuardActivity.class.getName()
            + ".LOCATION_READY");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    // minimum every 30 minutes, 300 kilometers 
    this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(this.provider, 30000,
            300000, pendingIntent);
}

private void cancelLocationUpdates() {
    this.locationManager.removeUpdates(pendingIntent);
}
```

Thanks to all of you who tried to help me.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. Feel free to mark your own answer here as accepted *(when the time is up for that)*, [that's even encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). This way it's clear for search-engine users which answer fixed the problem for you and they don't waste time with understanding an answer that might not help them after all.

Answer (score 0):

try `locationManager.removeUpdates(gpsl);`